# visual studio 2005 crashes when watch variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, crash

In visual studio 2005 debugging mode, when I watch this kind of variable :

```
vector<vector<_variant_>>
```

with specific contents, the IDE will crash.
Like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <comutil.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "comsuppwd.lib")

using namespace std;

typedef vector<_variant_t> TABLE_ROW;
typedef vector<TABLE_ROW> MEMORY_TABLE;


int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MEMORY_TABLE data;

    TABLE_ROW row;
    row.push_back(_variant_t("abcdefg"));
    row.push_back(_variant_t("b"));
    row.push_back(_variant_t("c"));
    row.push_back(_variant_t("d"));
    row.push_back(_variant_t(5.1));
    row.push_back(_variant_t(6.2));
    row.push_back(_variant_t(7.4));
    row.push_back(_variant_t(8.5));
    row.push_back(_variant_t(9.7));
    row.push_back(_variant_t("1"));
    row.push_back(_variant_t(0));
    row.push_back(_variant_t(0));
    row.push_back(_variant_t(1));
    row.push_back(_variant_t("eeeeeee"));
    data.push_back(row);

    TABLE_ROW row2;
    row2.push_back(_variant_t(5.1));
    row2.push_back(_variant_t(6.2));
    row2.push_back(_variant_t(7.4));
    row2.push_back(_variant_t(8.5));
    row2.push_back(_variant_t(9.7));
    data.push_back(row2);



    printf( "hello, bug\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Add a break point at

```
printf( "hello, bug\n");
```

then start debugging, when it break at the break point, then watch variable

```
data
```

then the IDE will crash.
Visual studio 2010 or higher version works fine.

How can I fix it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's a bug in a ten year old version of Visual Studio. There's no practical way of fixing it. Why not move to a newer version?

Comment: If so, I will think about it. But our computer may not be fast enough to run new version. Thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a bug in this ancient visual studio.

A new compiler is not luxury. C++ language is evolving. Modern C++ features are exciting and can make your code much more succinct and reliable. Visual Studio 2005 does not support any of these features.

And if your computer is not fast enough to run a Visual Studio 2010 (at least), I would prefer not using an IDE and invest in a modern compiler. MinGW, for example, has a good support of C++11.